# Map a column to return hours, minutes, seconds without days

Tags: python, date

I am mapping a function to a Dataframe column that integers (relating to seconds) to return hours, minutes and seconds into a new column

```
.map(lambda row: datetime.timedelta(seconds=row))
```

**However it returns**

```
      Sec            Time
      0     0 days 00:00:00
      1     0 days 00:00:01
      2     0 days 00:00:02
      3     0 days 00:00:03
```

**Im expecting to get the same without the "0 days" component**

Comment: Just get the last 8 characters then

Comment: `str(timedelta(seconds=423233))[8:]`

Comment: @rej it will return string though. If  I want to use this in a graph, I'd rather have that in time type

Comment: you can then cast it to datetime